# 'md-card' is not a known element in material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I working on a web application using angular 4 and Material 2. I have I get this error

```
parse errors:
'md-card' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<h2>Nothing to show</h2>
[ERROR ->]<md-card>Simple card</md-card>
"): ng:///AppAccessModule/SPLoginComponent.html@1:0
    at syntaxError
```

When I try to use material in a component nested twice inside a folder

these is my structure:

```
  -----Components(folder)
  -------Auth(folder)
  --------Login(component1)
  --------Signup(component2)
```

But if I next once like this:

```
  -------Auth(folder)
  --------Login(component 1)
  --------Signup(component2)
```

I don't have any issue what should I do to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: do you have `MdCardModule` added in your `AppModule` imports ?

Comment: @Faisal yes. and everything works file if I nest the cogent once.

Comment: need more details about you app then.

Comment: @Faisal here is the application https://github.com/gbrigens/boom, after upgrading it to the latest version of angular 4.3.6 and material 2 latest version I started getting those error but the one on this link is working haven't committed the changes yet.

Comment: can you fork and commit latest changes and share the link ?

Comment: @Faisal I have committed the changes with the new source code.

Comment: The repo contains only the files from default angular-cli app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152848/discussion-between-gerald-brigen-and-faisal).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `src/app/modules/app-access.module.ts` import the `MdCardModule`:

```
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular/material';
```

And add it in the imports:

```
imports: [ 
        ....
        MdCardModule, 
    ],
```

If you are using any other components from material 2, add those as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

@NgModule({ ..
 imports: [..
MatCardModule]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the `MaterialModule`, which was deprecated in beta-3.
Either import all the Material modules, that you want to use separately, i.e. the `MdCardModule` or create your own `BoomMaterialModule`, where you import and export all the Material modules, you want to use in your app.

wrong:

```
import { MaterialModule,MdSelectModule } from '@angular/material';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

either import `MdCardModule`

or create BoomMaterialModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  MdButtonModule,
  MdButtonToggleModule,
  MdCardModule,
  ...
  MdExpansionModule
} from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdButtonToggleModule,
    MdCardModule,
    ...
    MdExpansionModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MdButtonModule,
    MdButtonToggleModule,
    MdCardModule,
    ...
    MdExpansionModule
  ]
})
export class BoomMaterialModule {
}
```

Comment: `MaterialModule` is still supported until beta.8, and will be removed in the next release, beta.9. The code shared on github is for an older version of Material and angular.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a shared.module.ts or you just importing the modules individually make sure to import the Angular Material modules after Angular's **BrowserModule**, as the import order matters for **NgModules**